# Angular cli can not be installed on ubuntu 17.04

Tags: command-line, 17.04, nodejs, npm

I'm trying to install `@angular/cli` on my Linux (Ubuntu 17.04), I have updated `nodejs` to latest version 8.2.1 and `npm` 5.3.0, but when I run command `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli` installation is looping on this:

```
gyp verb command install [ '8.2.1' ]
gyp verb install input version string "8.2.1"
gyp verb install installing version: 8.2.1
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version not already installed, continuing with install 8.2.1
gyp verb ensuring nodedir is created /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp/8.2.1
gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp/8.2.1"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp"
gyp verb tmpdir == cwd automatically will remove dev files after to save disk space
```

How can I fix this issue? I'm getting insane because of this

Comment: Why do you use sudo in front of the command?

Comment: Because of permissions errors, first I was trying without sudo but same issue

Comment: Same problem on 16.04LTS

Answer (score 2):

It's not pretty but manually creating the missing directory seems to work.

```
cd /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/
mkdir .node-gyp
mkdir .node-gyp/8.2.1
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Worst part is there's not even anything in that directory after installation.